# Approach to hold an authenticated user's info and roles throughout the web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

What would be the best approach to hold an authenticated user's info and roles throughout the application (after sign-on)? I would like to avoid using session. I would like to hold user info like firstname, lastname, email, department, etc..This will be MVC 3 web application.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in-built `Membership Provider` in `MVC`

Comment: Can you give me an example? I don't see much details on LDAP for MVC?